# Split Array up into columns in same row

Tags: html, arrays, powershell, powercli

My code is below and does the job well enough.  However I would like to have the VM's list say 10 VMs, then start another "column" in the same row. Almost like make them bullets. A certain cluster could contain almost 100 VMs and having it list 100 VMs can be messy and sort of an eye strain.

Is this possible?

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:palegoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$array = @()

$clusters = Get-Cluster | sort Name

Foreach ($cluster in $clusters)
{

 $hosts = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vmhost
 $gethosts =  ($hosts.Name | % { (get-vmhost $_).Name;}) -join ';';
 $gethosts = $gethosts.Replace(';',"`r`n")
 $vms = get-cluster -name $cluster | get-vm
 $getvms =  ($vms.Name | % { (get-vm $_).Name;}) -join ';';
 $getvms = $getvms.Replace(';',"`r`n")
 $vmCount = get-cluster -name $cluster | select Name, @{N=“NumVM“;E={($_ | Get-VM).Count}}

    $obj = New-Object PSObject

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Cluster" -Value $cluster
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hosts" -Value $gethosts
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Number of VMs" -Value $vmCount.NumVM
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "VMs" -Value $getvms

    $array += $obj
}

$array |select Cluster, Hosts, "Number of VMs", VMs|  ConvertTo-HTML -head $a| out-file c:\temp\test\ClusterInfo.html -force
```

In my current script, the VM's basically just are listed and do "fit the screen" and the row will adjust as needed.  However, is there a better way to auto adjust and list VM's in a cleaner way?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You should post an example of your current output and an example of what you want the output to be like.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to leave the table as it is and define a style with alternating row colors:

```
$a = @"
<style>
BODY {
  background-color:peachpuff;
}
TABLE {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
TH {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color:thistle
}
TR:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
TR:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
TD {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-color:palegoldenrod
}
</style>
"@
```